# how to write the stream to memory stream?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void doprocess(TcpClient client)
{    
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    Stream clStream = client.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer_1 = new byte[8192];

    int count = clStream.Read(buffer_1, 0, buffer_1.Length);

    while (count > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer_1, 0, count);

        //the below line doesn't gives response and code hangs here 
        count = clStream.Read(buffer_1, 0, buffer_1.Length);         
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to write one stream to another? I want to use this `Stream` twice, which is why I need to write it to the `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 4 the copying part is really easy:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
client.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);
```

If you're not using .NET 4, then code similar to what you've already got is basically the same thing.

**However**, note that this (and any other attempt) will only work if the network stream has been closed - otherwise the `Read` call will block waiting for more data. I suspect that's what's going wrong for you - and it's a fundamental problem.

If your network stream isn't closed, then it's unclear how you'd really want it to behave - should the two readers of the "split" stream basically read any buffered data, but then block until there's new data otherwise? The buffered data could be removed when it's been read from both streams, of course. If that is what you're after, I don't think there's anything in .NET to help you particularly - and it's probably pretty tricky.

If you could give us more context of what you're trying to do (and what the TcpClient is connecting to) that would really help.

Comment: @purvang: Ah, so you're the server, not the client... and what's the client going to do? If it doesn't close the connection, you can read forever...

Comment: TcpClient client = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient(); //it accepts the client request

Comment: client just gives the request in the browser and i just scan the request whether it is proper or not and then send it to original server.So i used this stream to while scanning the request, so i need to use two stream one to display in form and other for scanning.i read that to use this stream twice  i should write it to memory stream. Please guide me !! thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @purvang: So this is an HTTP request? You'll need to use something which knows how to understand HTTP requests - and in particular where the end of the request comes. Why are you trying to write an HTTP server at this low level anyway? There are higher level abstractions which would make your life *much* simpler...

Comment: Yes it is an HTTP request,are you suggesting me to use "sockets" (high level abstraction) instead of tcpclient?  Regarding the end of request  string text=clientstreamreader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @purvang: No, sockets are a *low*-level abstraction. A higher-level abstraction would be something like `HttpListener`. Using `ReadToEnd` won't work if the client doesn't close the connection - which it won't if it's trying to use a keep-alive connection.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code hangs on `clStream.Read` is because you are tying to read 8192 bytes from the socket but on the other side no-one is writing that many bytes. So the client just sits there and waits for the other side to send the required number of bytes. Depending on the protocol you are trying to implement over TCP there must be some indincation from the server how much data it intends to send so that the client knows in advance and only tries to read that many bytes.

For example in the HTTP protocol the server sends in the headers the Content-Length header to indicate to the clients how much data is going to be sent in the body.