# Network Programming : receiving image file in dynamic Image Object in TCP client server

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, network-programming

um use this code to store a received Image in the Hard disk Memory 
i try to edit this code to store the received Image file in dynamic Image Object with out storing in the Hard disk Memory

```
    private void StartReceiving()
    {
        try
        {
              string hstServer = Dns.GetHostName();
             IPAddress ipaLocal ="127.0.0.1";


            if (tlsServer == null)
            {
                tlsServer = new TcpListener(ipaLocal, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
            } 
            tlsServer.Start(); 
            TcpClient tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient(); 
            strRemote = tclServer.GetStream(); 
            int bytesSize = 0;
            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];
            bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, 2048);
           FileName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
           try
           {
               strLocal = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
           }catch(Exception exp)
           {
               strLocal = new FileStream(FileName.Substring(0,5), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
           }
            downBuffer = new byte[2048];

            bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, 2048);

            downBuffer = new byte[2048];

            while ((bytesSize = strRemote.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            strLocal.Close();
            strRemote.Close();

        }
    }
```

edit by using CopyTo in .net 4

```
            tlsServer.Start(); 
            TcpClient tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient();
           tclServer.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);

            //Get the image out of the stream
            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);


        }
        finally
        {
            m = Image.FromStream(strLocal);
            strLocal.Close();
            strRemote.Close();

        }
```

Comment: So you want to store it in memory in an `Image` object?

Answer (score 2):

As per the detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529642/how-to-write-the-stream-to-memory-stream):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
//This call will block until the client disconnects though
tclServer.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);

//Get the image out of the stream
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Exception  : Parameter is not valid.